# Print Statement into a variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to scrap some image links. Using this coded I managed to get them all

```py
images = []
images = page_soup.findAll('img')

for image in images:
    print(image.get('src'))
```

now I would like to write the links into a csv file, is there a way to turn my print statement into a variable so that it will write into a row?

here is my code so far

```py
with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([name, images, datetime.now()])
```

Update I changed my code to

```py
images = []
images = page_soup.findAll('img')

with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for image in images:
        writer.writerow([image.get_text(), image.get('src'), datetime.now()])
```

but still having a formatting issue in csv, I want all image links to print in same row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9xnZ.jpg)

Comment: "Here is my code so far" – If it doesn't work (which is why you are here), what happens instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just refactor Your Code to use feteched data to fill Your cvs.

**Like this could work :**

```
images = []
images = page_soup.findAll('img')

with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for image in images:
        writer.writerow([image.get_text(), image.get('src'), datetime.now()])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked but it made a new row for every image link and also duplicated all my other scraped data with each image link . Instead of what I would have liked which is all the links being in one row.

Comment: thats because, there is append flag set in in `open('index.csv', 'a')`. If You want the will to being erased just open it with write flag. 
 ANd what You mean with in one row ? You want them being separated be coma ? just give example of row which fit Your requirements

Comment: Thank you for replying to me again. I posted an image of how I would like the csv formatted